# Web API call to a SOAP Web Service returns "Unable to connect" error

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I have an IIS set-up for my Web API application. One of the functions in my Web API calls on a SOAP web service. When I try to call on my Web API using my other project, it returns a `Unable to connect to the remote server` error.

Strange thing is, when I run my Web API application in debug mode, the error does not show and it works as intended.

Here is a rough draft of how I call the Web API:

```
static async Task RunAsyncBlogs()
{


   using (var client = new HttpClient())
   {
       client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://ph-lb-d12/my_webapi/");
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/xml"));

       var success = "";

       // HTTP GET
       HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/Controller/DoAction");

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {

                    success = "yes";
                }
                else
                {
                    success = "no";
                }


    }
 }
```

Next, here is how I call on the web service from my Web API solution:
Assume that `GetXMLData` is the function that the API Controller calls

```
public XmlDocument GetXMLData()
{

    var xmlRaw = "";
    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    WS.Service webService = new WS.Service();

    xmlRaw = webService.DoAction("TEST").OuterXml; //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS

    xmldoc.Load(xmlRaw);

    return xmldoc;

}
```

Assume that this all works when the Web API solution is in debug mode. But when it isn't. It returns this:

```
<Error><Message>An error has occurred.</Message><ExceptionMessage>Unable to connect to the remote server</ExceptionMessage><ExceptionType>System.Net.WebException</ExceptionType><StackTrace> at cemws.Core.PLI.GetXMLFeed() in e:\micron\cem\PROTOTYPE\cemws\src\cemws\Core\PLI.cs:line 70    at cemws.Controllers.IntegrationController.GetPLIFeed() in e:\micron\cem\PROTOTYPE\cemws\src\cemws\Controllers\IntegrationController.cs:line 42    at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass10.&lt;GetExecutor&gt;b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)    at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()  at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.&lt;InvokeActionAsyncCore&gt;d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()  at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.&lt;ExecuteAsync&gt;d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()  at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.&lt;SendAsync&gt;d__1.MoveNext()</StackTrace><InnerException><Message>An error has occurred.</Message><ExceptionMessage>A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
10.2.1.3:8080</ExceptionMessage><ExceptionType>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException</ExceptionType><StackTrace> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)    at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket&amp; socket, IPAddress&amp; address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&amp; exception)</StackTrace></InnerException></Error>
```

Comment: How're you calling `GetXMLData` from the api?

Comment: The controller calls `GetXMLData` . It works in debug mode. But when I use IIS, it doesn't

Comment: And is `GetXMLData` part of a wcf service?

Comment: No. Oh, I'm sorry I forgot to mention what the WCF function is. It's `webService.DoAction("TEST").OuterXml;` - this produces the error

Comment: you also have another `DoAction` in your controller, right?

Comment: Yes. That is what calls the function `GetXMLData`.

Comment: How are you calling that `GetXmlData`? Show us your `web.config`.